# How to optimize the rendering of multiple instances of the same element, with the same property value

Tags: lit-element

I have a component based on lit-element that is rendering a combobox with about 200 entries. The rendering of the template is taking about 0.20s.

```
html`
    <select>
        ${this.list.map((o) => html`
            <option id="${index}"
                    @click="${this.handleClick}">${o}</option>`
        )}
    </select>`
```

I'm rendering the same component multiple times, with the same value for the property list. The rendering is taking 0.20s each time, which is quite long if I'm rendering 10 instances of the component. Is there any way to optimize this, specially when knowing that the generated template is the same for every instance of the component ?

Comment: Use `repeat` directive for efficiency. Refer https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/writing-templates#repeating-templates

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intermediate variable

```
html`
<select>
    ${this.options}
</select>`
```

with a function like this

```
    this.options = this.list.map(
        (o) => html`
            <option id="${index}" @click="${this.handleClick}">${o}</option>`
    );
```